# What do the chars %7D mean in an url query?

Tags: python, google-app-engine, url, jinja2, webapp2

If I access my webapp with the url

`/vi/5907399890173952.html`

then it works but when I look in the log files then googlebot is trying to access a similar url which generates an exception:

`/vi/5907399890173952.html%7D%7D`

what does it mean and how can it be handled as an exception? The message from python is:

```
 /vi/5251302833520640.html%7D%7D 404 20ms 0kb Mozilla/5.0 (compatible; Googlebot/2.1; +http://www.google.com/bot.html) module=default version=release140319
66.249.67.109 - - [19/Mar/2014:07:53:32 -0700] "GET /vi/5251302833520640.html%7D%7D HTTP/1.1" 404 84 - "Mozilla/5.0 (compatible; Googlebot/2.1; +http://www.google.com/bot.html)" ms=21 cpu_ms=0 cpm_usd=0.000009 app_engine_release=1.9.1 instance=00c61b117c0bc0f980f2a37a6ac534786055d3ab
E 2014-03-19 15:53:32.678
get() takes exactly 3 arguments (2 given)
```

The regex that I use for the url is

`('/vi/(\d+)(\.html?)?', NewHandler)`

Answer (score 163, accepted):

`%7D` is the ASCII code for the } character, which is probably leaking through from a template...

Comment: Twig was freaking me!

Comment: i was freaked by blade!

Comment: I've just forgot to remove a `}` from a variable reference in js template literal

Comment: TypeScript templates with IDE autocomplete spare my brains.

Comment: wasted 1 hour checking on this

Comment: oh wow....LMFAO

Comment: This just saved my sanity, thank you!

Answer (score 1):

You need to use `` ` `` instead of `"` or `'`.

For example:

```
`http://localhost:8080/api/v1/user-profile/${userProfileID}/image/upload`
```

and not:

```
"http://localhost:8080/api/v1/user-profile/${userProfileID}/image/upload"
```